# Firebase configuration warning message .indexOn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Considering the following firebase.rules.json :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "true",
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    }
  }
}
```

Why do I still have this warning on chrome devtools?

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. 
Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /users 
to your security rules for better performance
```

I also tried (without success):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "true",
    ".indexOn": "email"
  }
}
```

Here is the query throwing the error:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild("email").equalTo(userEmail).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) { 
         #do smth 
      } else { 
         #do smth 
      };
    };
```

How should I change my configuration in order to fix this?

Any input greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show the query that raises this warning?

Comment: Hello Frank, Initial question edited with the query.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't immediately see what's going wrong here. Maybe somebody else spots the problem.